# Using Dynamic Queries Across Multiple Databases to Change Views

Tags: sql-server, dynamic-sql

I am seeking to run a query to modify views across multiple databases (See the initial question [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/150798/change-a-specific-line-of-a-view-with-conditions).) and was able to find how to get it.  I've now run into the problem that if I run this from master (Where I'm sure it has to run from) i receive null results.  However, if i go to a specific database and run the dynamic query there, i get the views i'm looking to modify (the intended result).

This is the action I want performed on each database:

`select @strResult = definition from sys.sql_modules where object_id = object_id('view')`

What do i need to do to ensure that I get this information back?

Comment: You need to make this call dynamic, much like the other statements, and use the databasename.sys.sql_modules, otherwise it references sys.sql_modules of the current database.

Comment: Let me try that, because at this juncture, that is _painfully_ obvious now that its been pointed out.

Comment: @nic this doesn't appear to be the magic bullet.  Its still returning null.  Perhaps it is a permissions issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need dynamic SQL for this, like in your other answer. Here is my approach:

- Build the SQL command you want to run in each database
- The `IF` check in the command ensures you only try to alter a view in a database where that view is found
- Generate an execution command like `EXEC databasename.sys.sp_executesql` so the command doesn't have to be database-aware
- Go to town. Cursor vs. while loop is just a preference.
- Note that if someone uses tabs, comments, carriage returns etc. before or between `CREATE` and `VIEW` when creating the view initially, it becomes more complex to accurately change a `CREATE` to an `ALTER`, but the other answer didn't deal with that anyway (and assumed case insensitivity). This is safer because it doesn't assume collation and doesn't replace *all* instances of `create view` with `alter view` (those could be in comments, string literals, etc.)

Good starting point:

```
DECLARE @view nvarchar(512) = N'[dbo].[viewname]',
        @exec nvarchar(512),
        @db   sysname,
        @sql  nvarchar(max);

SET @sql = N'DECLARE @str nvarchar(max);
  SELECT @str = OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID(@view));
  IF UPPER(LEFT(@str, 11)) = N''CREATE VIEW''
  BEGIN
    SET @str = STUFF(@str, 1, 11, N''ALTER VIEW'');
    SET @str = REPLACE(@str, N''original string'', ''replace string'');
    PRINT DB_NAME();
    PRINT @str;
    --EXEC sys.sp_executesql @str;
  END';

DECLARE c CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR
  SELECT QUOTENAME(name) FROM sys.databases
  WHERE state = 0 AND database_id > 4;

OPEN c;

FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @db;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS <> -1
BEGIN
  SET @exec = @db + N'.sys.sp_executesql';
  EXEC @exec @sql, N'@view nvarchar(512)', @view;
  FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @db;
END

CLOSE c; DEALLOCATE c;
```

When you are happy with the output (note that `PRINT` will not show everything for a larger view), comment the `PRINT` statements and uncomment the `EXEC`). Further reading:

- [Execute a Command in the Context of Each Database in SQL Server using sp_ineachdb](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5686/execute-a-command-in-the-context-of-each-database-in-sql-server-using-spineachdb/)
- [Validate the contents of large dynamic SQL strings in SQL Server](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3185/validate-the-contents-of-large-dynamic-sql-strings-in-sql-server/)

Answer (score 1):

The call needs to be dynamic for the databases, as does the object_id.

This is basic (does not check for offline databases and the like), but gives you an idea as to how it would function, looping through the databases in sys.databases.

```
DECLARE @viewDef NVARCHAR(max);
DECLARE @DatabaseList sysname;
SELECT @DatabaseList = MIN(name) FROM sys.databases;
WHILE @DatabaseList IS NOT NULL
BEGIN

SELECT @viewDef = 'SELECT Definition from ' + QUOTENAME(@DatabaseList) + '.sys.sql_modules WHERE OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID(N'+CHAR(39)+QUOTENAME(@DatabaseList) +'.dbo.view'+CHAR(39)+');'
--PRINT @viewDef
EXEC (@viewDef)

SELECT @DatabaseList = MIN(name) FROM sys.databases WHERE name > @DatabaseList;
END
```